# User Authentication in indy tcp server

Tags: delphi, authentication, indy, tcpserver

i am trying to write a telnet type program to read data from indy tcpserver

I want the user to first authenticate .. which is easy .. but the problem is where do I keep this authentication result so when the client executes another command, my tcpserver would know that this is an authenticated user and return data accordingly.

I hope I was specific.. and sorry for my English i'm from Venezuela.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TIdPeerThread` in Indy 9, and `TIdContext` in Indy 10, both have a `Data` property that you can store whatever you want in it.

A better option is to derive a new class from `TIdPeerThread`/`TIdServerContext` instead, add your custom fields/properties to that class as needed, and then assign that class to the server's `ThreadClass`/`ContextClass` property.  Each command handler can then type-cast the provided `APeerThread`/`AContext` object to your class type to access your custom data.

You should look at the source code for Indy's own components that support user authentication, such as `TIdPOP3Server` and `TIdSMTPServer`, to see how they persist authentication data between commands.

Comment: Remy, thanx for rapid answer... i have never worked with tidcontext before.. i will try with this.. if anything i will ask for a little help if you dont mind... thank you